# What is the difference ( if there is any ) between ein Video zu and ein Video über ein Thema machen?

Tags: preposition

What is the difference between these 2 sentences and in the usage of both prepositions über and zu ?

> Ich habe ein Video über Aktiv und Passiv gemacht.

> Bitte machen Sie ein Video zu Dativ und Akkusativ.

Are both prepositions in this case interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a subtle difference in the usage.

When someone uses "über", this gives the impression, that the person tries to give an overview about a topic.

When someone uses "zu/zur/zum", this gives the impression, that the person wants to add details to a topic or to a broader discourse.

Because the difference is pretty minor, I think in your examples, the prepositions are fully interchangeable.

> Ich habe ein Video zu Aktiv und Passiv gemacht.
>
> Bitte machen Sie ein Video über Dativ und Akkusativ.

Comment: I think with a verb, say in *Wir sprechen über Akkusativ und Dativ*, only *über* is possible, I'm not sure why. I couldn't find this meaning of *zu* in DWDS, did I miss something?

Comment: There are cases where you can do that.

Wir drehen zu Akkusativ und Passiv ein Video.